# MP critical region for discrete random variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, inference, discrete-data

> Let $x$ be a discrete random variable with probability mass function $p(x)$, where $x$ belongs to $\{-1, 0, 1, 2, 3\}$. To test $H_0\!: p(x) = p_o(x)$ vs. $p(x) = p_1(x)$, where for above mentioned values of $x$ the respective values of $p_o(x)$ and $p_1(x)$ are
>
> \begin{align}p_o(x)\!: \quad.01  \quad.02   \quad.05   \quad.32  \quad.60  \\
> p_1(x)\!: \quad.04  \quad.08   \quad.25   \quad.03  \quad.60 \end{align}
>
> we have
>
> A) $\{1\}$ is MP critical region for $\alpha = 0.05$
>   B) $\{-1,1\}$ is MP critical region for $\alpha=0.06$
>   C) $\{-1,0,1\}$ is MP critical region for $\alpha =0.08$
>   but D) $\{-1, 0\}$ is not MP critical region for $\alpha = 0.03$

I just want to check my progress thus far.  This is what I have tried:

Consider case C, inside the critical region $\{-1, 1\}$, we have $L_0/L_1 \le 0.25$; outside the critical region, we have $L_0/L_1 \ge 0.25$ so $\{-1, 1\}$ must be a critical region $\alpha = 0.06$.

Now consider D, inside the critical region $\{-1, 0\} L_0/L_1 \le 0.25$; but outside the critical region at $x=1$, $L_0/L_1 < 0.25$, so $\{-1, 0\}$ cannot be MP critical region for $\alpha = 0.03$.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Can you add some more about what you have tried so far?

Comment: yes , and this is the online link of the corresponding page in the  book its ques no. 119                                              https://books.google.co.in/books?id=i9vvBwAAQBAJ&pg=PP39&lpg=PP39&dq=discrete+random+variable+MP+critical+region+net+exam&source=bl&ots=38ZnrN4XgH&sig=V3ww2wB5PHcJ9Zk85LGpYtFY3wY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihxoXe6qnRAhVJqI8KHXUJBT0Q6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=discrete%20random%20variable%20MP%20critical%20region%20net%20exam&f=false